# sql server - merge data of two columns into another column if there are duplicate values in id

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

My Table looks like below

```
Id  Message
1    A
1    B
2    C
2    D
3    E
3    F
```

i want another column with data merge like below

```
1
a
b
2
c
d
3
e
f
```

Comment: I believe the order is important? Are you sure you want the data that way? This seems more like a reporting or visual tool task.

Comment: I only see multiple rows no multiple columns. also, what is column names?

Comment: yes it is more of visual thing can we achieve this

Comment: @SonalBorkar lets say the number column is id and alphabetical column in message

Comment: @SonalBorkar 

id  mesage

1      a

1      b

2      c

2      d

like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
;WITH Data AS
(
    SELECT
        V.ID,
        V.Code,
        DenseRankByID = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY V.ID),
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY V.ID ASC, V.Code ASC)
    FROM
        (VALUES
        (1, 'A'),
        (1, 'B'),
        (2, 'C'),
        (2, 'D'),
        (3, 'E'),
        (3, 'F')) AS V(ID, Code)
),
AddedValues AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [Value] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), D.ID),
        D.DenseRankByID,
        RowNumber = 0
    FROM
        Data AS D

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        [Value] = D.Code,
        D.DenseRankByID,
        D.RowNumber
    FROM
        Data AS D
)
SELECT
    A.[Value],
    A.DenseRankByID,
    A.RowNumber
FROM
    AddedValues AS A
ORDER BY
    A.DenseRankByID,
    A.RowNumber
```

Result:

```
Value   DenseRankByID   RowNumber
1       1               0
A       1               1
B       1               2
2       2               0
C       2               3
D       2               4
3       3               0
E       3               5
F       3               6
```

You can omit the last 2 columns on the `SELECT` if you don't want them displayed (don't remove them from the `ORDER BY` though).

The Dense Rank is used to give a different number for each value from the 1st column, while the row number is just to differentiate all the other values from the 2nd column. Then we get all different values from the 1st column (first part of the `UNION ALL`) and add them to all the other values from the 2nd column.